How to properly combine Versioned Transaction with Transaction?
I am trying to combine versioned transaction received from Jupiter to combine with another transaction instruction I have. Is there a way to properly do that? Or do I have to convert other transaction instruction to a versioned transaction?

This question is similar to: Convert VersionedTransaction to Transaction. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
